# How to get all addresses that have had successful transaction in the last polygon block?

Tags: web3js, events, blocks, polygon

I need to listen for special events on some contract addresses in Polygon/Matic blockchain; However, my provider has limitations on the number of possible subscriptions. So, I have to get all the events (or if not possible, only the address of some desired smart contracts that have had at least one successful transaction in the last block). How can I do it through `web3.js`?

Comment: if you want all event logs then filter logs is a bad idea. some events could be anonymous and only have `Data` fields but not `Topics` field. Still such contract can be of importance,  depending on what is your knowledge of the contract internals. So, I would go for scanning all blocks and all transactions. Once you get a transaction, you fetch it's receipt and inside the receipt there are logs.

Comment: All events for polygon will take about 80GB of space, this is what I have at least